logistic regression: categorical predictor with many levels - appropriate group sizes
I'm estimating a logistic regression model with a categorical predictor with 11 groups. I'm wondering whether I can/should exclude some of these groups (D-K, maybe C as well; see below) b/c of small n per event. Groups D-K aren't that interesting anyway, I'm mostly interested in the comparison of A, B, and C. This is the distribution of my data (A-K: groups; Y/N: event):
    Y     N
A  96   246
B  13   103
C   2    69
D   1     6
E   2     4
F   1     3
G   1     2
H   1     1
I   0     1
J   0     1
K   0     1


Sure, you can define the variables like you want. In general, it is not advised to compress your variables too much since you lose some information then, but in this case it would be a very good idea indeed since those very sparse groups can cause problems and are not even of interest.
Two paths from here I can think about are:

You discard groups D until K and only use A, B and C, but then you do not use all your data and this might not be optimal/wanted

You make another variable 'other' that contains the information of D until K, so in the end you have 4 groups instead of 10+ and you can still see if A, B and C are different from each other and 'the rest'.


